# How can i rewrite the subscriber in RXJS with rxpy

Tags: python, typescript

I don't know how to change the Subscriber of RXJS to the form of Python, which is not effective.

Typescript USES the GRPC stream form and plugs in the RXJS Subscriber. Python doesn't know how to write it.

RXJS code

```
import * as grpc from 'grpc';
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';

export function subscribeToWorkspace(
  input: WorkspaceSubscriptionInput,
): Observable<EventPayload> {
  return new Observable<EventPayload>((observer: Subscriber<EventPayload>) => {
    log(`opening stream for subscription ${input.toString()}`);

    const stream: grpc.ClientReadableStream<EventPayload> =
      client.subscribeToWorkspace(input, metadata);

    stream.on('data', (eventPayload: EventPayload) => {
      if (observer.closed) {
        return;
      }
      observer.next(eventPayload);
    });

    stream.on('error', (err) => observer.error(err));
    stream.on('end', () => observer.complete());

    return () => {
      log(`closing stream for subscription ${input.toString()}`);
      stream.cancel();
    };
  });
}
```

Python code

```
from rx import of
def subscribe_to_workspace(cls, subsinput: WorkspaceSubscriptionInput) -> Observable:
        return of(cls.client.SubscribeToWorkspace(subsinput))
```

Rxpy does not work. What should Python do

Answer (score 0):

```
# pip install rx

from rx import Observable, Observer
def get_strings(observer):
    observer.on_next("Ram")
    observer.on_next("Mohan")
    observer.on_next("Shyam")
    observer.on_completed()
class PrintObserver(Observer):
   def on_next(self, value):
       print("Received {0}".format(value))
   def on_completed(self):
       print("Finished")
   def on_error(self, error):
       print("Error: {0}".format(error))
source = Observable.create(get_strings)
source.subscribe(PrintObserver())
```